# How to plot inscribed circle in cytoscape.js nodes

Tags: cytoscape.js

i need to plot (in cytoscape.js) a circle inscibed to another circle.
I can make the external circle with:

```
shape:'ellipse',
height: 15,
width: 15,
'background-color': 'white',
'border-width':0.5,
'border-color':'black'
```

But how can i make the other circle inscribed?

EDIT: In particular, i have to put inside a white circle with black circumference, a smaller white circle with black circumference.

2th EDIT: 
I solved by creating a fake node (equal to real one but smaller) that follows the original when dragged or grabbed.

```
var compAtrr = cy.$('node[type = "originalnode"]');
    compAtrr.on('grabon drag',function(evt){
        var node = evt.target;
        var idnode = node.data('id');
        var fakenode = cy.$id(idnode+'fake');
        var ix = node.position('x');
        var iy = node.position('y');
        fakenode.position({
            x: ix,
            y: iy
        });
    });

    var fakeAtrr = cy.$('node[type = "fakenode"]');
    fakeAtrr.on('grabon drag',function(evt){
        var node = evt.target;
        var idnode = node.data('id');
        var l = idnode.length;
        idnode = idnode.slice(0,l-4); //remove 'fake' string
        var realnode = cy.$id(idnode);
        var ix = node.position('x');
        var iy = node.position('y');
        realnode.position({
            x: ix,
            y: iy
        });
    });
```

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [code pen](https://codepen.io/steevokovsky/pen/pxQYad?editors=1010), you can specify an inner circle by defining the background or a border:

```
style: [
    {
      selector: 'node',
      css: {
        'content': 'data(id)',
        'text-valign': 'center',
        'text-halign': 'center',
        'height': '60px',
        'width': '60px',
        'border-color': 'black',
        'border-opacity': '1',
        'border-width': '10px'
      }
    },
    ...
```

Comment: I have to put inside a white circle with black circumference, a smaller white circle with black circumference, so this method doesn't works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid this is not possible in Cytoscape.js. Your best bet is to use a background image.

You can also try setting border style to `double`, but this is very limited - you won't be able to change the distance between lines.

Comment: Good call! That could be the answer :D But  the question really is: is it really that necessary in the first place, it is still just styling and probably doesn't add anything other than that (and performance loss)

Answer (score 0):

You can draw arbitrary content on a node with one or more SVG background images.

Comment: Thanks. But if i don't want to use images, is it impossibile to do that, Right?